# Nightmare evaluation timed out

Tags: javascript, timeout, electron, nightmare

I'm trying to find an element by `XPath` expression in `nightmare` library. According to the docs, I should use evalution promises.

So I went with the following:

```
nightmare
    .goto('https://google.com')
    .wait(1000)
    .evaluate((query) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const elem = document.evaluate(query, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
            console.log(query);
            if (elem == null) {
                // Element not found
                reject(`element doesn't exist`);
                return;
            }

            // Resolve with the element
            resolve(elem);
        });
    }, '//body')
    .then(function(r) {
        console.log('Element found:');
        console.log(r);
    });
```

It doesn't seem to work, because I get the timeout error in the console:

> Error: Evaluation timed out after 30000msec.  Are you calling done()
>   or resolving your promises?
>       at J:\Projects\Te…\lib\actions.js:634

How can I fix this? Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As odd as this sounds, the `.goto()` method is timing out. Google blocks all sorts of calls. Can you try `http://example.com` to see if that returns correctly?

Comment: Try with a no http**s** url.

Comment: Also, within the Promise, you don't need `document.evaluate` - that is not a valid call. Within the first evaluate, `document` represents the DOM in the browser.

Comment: @RandyCasburn document's `.evaluate` method is a different method to evaluate DOM elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate

Comment: @RandyCasburn Oh, `http://example.com/` seem to work fine... Really weird!

Comment: Yes, see the XPath for second evalutate. So the Google was blocking you. Glad to help.

Comment: @RandyCasburn No, google is not blocking. Page is loading completely and javascript is being executed locally so it should work.